# Eigenvectors of singular matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I have the following problem (need to state that I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question, hope it is):

- for each velocity I have three set of eigenvalues: $\alpha_{12}$, $\alpha_{34}$, $\alpha_{56}$, where $\alpha_{2}$,=-$\alpha_{1}$ same is valid for 3,4 and 5,6. $\alpha_i$ can be complex depending on the velocity.
- Then I substitute the corresponding velocity and eigenvalue into a matrix **B**, which then is singular. det(**B**)=$0$ (highest values is $-5.2\cdot 10^{-16}$ according to Matlab). **B** is a symmetric matrix
- To obtain the eigenvector I use svd(**B**) in Matlab, which gives me three outputs: **U**, **S**, **V**
- I check when the values of **S** are zero, and select the corresponding column of **V** as eigenvector.

So my questions are:

1. Is this a correct approach to obtain the eigenvector of a singular matrix. If not what is a good way obtain these eigenvector.
2. I have read that svd output singular vector of the matrix, not the eigenvector of the matrix. What is the difference between a singular vector of matrix and an eigenvector.
3. If the approach is correct, than I would assume the eigenvector of $\alpha_1$ should be orthogonal to that of $\alpha_2$. Is this true, or am I bs'ing now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular vectors of a matrix $A$ are the eigenvectors of $A^* A$.  In the case of a real symmetric matrix $B$, the eigenvectors of $B$ are eigenvectors of $B^* B = B^2$, but not vice versa (in the case where $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ are both eigenvalues for some $\lambda \ne 0$).

To get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix in Matlab, use **eig**.

Comment: So, I can use the **eig**-function for a singular matrix? I though that **eig** is only valid for: **A**x $\neq 0$

Comment: I don't know where you would get that idea.  AFAIK eig is perfectly good for singular matrices.

Comment: So let me get this correct, regardless if the problem is **A**x = **b**, or **A**x = $0$. The **eig**-function in Matlab will work. I didn't know this!

Comment: @user5489 the eig function won't help you solve $Ax = b$.  However, it will work whenever $A$ is square, even if $Ax = 0$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Actually eig **can** help you solve $Ax=b$. Namely if $A = U^{-1} D U$ where $D$ is diagonal, and $Ax = b$ has a solution, then one such solution is $U^{-1} D^{+} U b$ where $D^+$ is diagonal with $D^+_{ii} = 1/D_{ii}$ whenever $D_{ii} \ne 0$.